# Dependent tests between two TestCase classes in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

In PHPUnit you can make one test to be depend on other test by using `@depends` annotation.
Is it possible to make whole TestCase dependent on test in other TestCase? Or at least make single test in one TestCase dependent on test in other TestCase?

I tried:

```
/**
 * @depends A::testMethodName
 */
```

But as I expected it doesn't work.

**Update:**

The exact situation looks like this: There is `class B` which uses `class A`. So I want to test `B` only if the tests for `A` (or one of it's tests) run without a failure. How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you want that? @depends enables you to use a return value from one test case for the next case. As both of these belong to the same class that is tested, this makes sense. If you want to use the return value of one testCase in a different testCase (for a different class?), why not use Mock objects so you can avoid having dependencies. I can see no reason why this would be a good idea, maybe you can explain a bit more.

Comment: I use @depends to ensure that tests won't be marked as Failure but as Skipped when the tests that they depend on fail. I don't return value from those tests, I don't need one.

Answer (score 15):

Exploiting dependencies are extremely important! The loose coupling as referred to is for actual application architecture not for unit test cases. If there is logical dependencies built in to functional execution is is always a good idea to exploit those dependencies.

Using [test doubling](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html) is appropriate for SOA where dependencies cannot be mapped to a particular failure within a black box **AND** the service is not reliable. This is not appropriate for inter application classes.

[You definitely would want to use this type of functionality](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/826-Test-Dependencies-in-PHPUnit-3.4.html) if there is logical dependencies between test classes. [The concept to be grasped](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Kuhn08aJExample.pdf) from unit testing is it's ability to isolate defects to particular components immediately.

This functionality IS available on PHPUnit v 3.7.13. However, the only way this will work is if you run PHPUnit on a directory which contains both TestCase classes.

For example with this folder structure

```bsh
- application\dep
   |- BTest.php
   |- CTest.php
```

The classes...

```
class BTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @depends CTest::testADomino
     */
    public function testDominoDependent()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

and...

```
class CTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testADomino()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

This is the result

```bsh
C:\Users\Josh>C:\xampp\php\phpunit.bat "C:\xampp\htdocs\BeAgile\applications\sto
cklogger\tests\dep"
PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

SF

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) CTest::testADomino
Failed asserting that false is true.

C:\xampp\htdocs\BeAgile\applications\stocklogger\tests\dep\CTest.php:7

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1, Skipped: 1.
```

You could have both test case classes in the same file but that would be a poor structure. It is not necessary to "make sure" one test runs before the other.

As an agile coach I see test doubling far too often in large organizations where specialized segments want to avoid having build failures when another components makes changes that causes test failure. This of course defeats the entire purpose of the unit tests which is to identify component failures before the end user does.

Comment: I tried this on PHPUnit 5.7.20 and this doesn't seem to be the case, (no idea if it used to be though) it just skips B and runs C.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore (testing on 9.x) as explained in another answer by Ekown , `@Depends` should be used (with capital D)

Comment: On PHPUnit 11 it's reporting "Metadata in doc-comments is deprecated". On document they use `#[Depends(...)]` but there is no example for class, only function. Is there any updated sample for this?

Answer (score 8):

For those who are still wondering about this question, you can use the `@Depends`reference instead of the `@depends`. It seems that the lowercase version can only be used in an inter-functional manner while the capital can be used class-to-class.

```
/**
 * @Depends FirstTest::testMethodName
 */
```

Make sure that **the depended test class will be run before the actual test class** that depends on it. You can do this by declaring the order of the test classes in the **testsuite** in the `phpunit.xml`.

```
<phpunit
        bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php"
        colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="App\\Tests">
            <directory>./test</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="sample-testsuite">
         <directory>./test/FirstTest.php</directory>
         <directory>./test/SecondTest.php</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Then, you run the testsuite.

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite sample-testsuite
```

I have only tested this with *6.1.0+* versions. You can see the discussion about this issue [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2647). Thanks :)

Comment: `@Depends` is skipped entirely. There is no "uppercase" variant and never was. As mentioned in other answer: use `@depends` and make sure that both files are in the same directory.

Comment: @Krzysiek, actually there is, and I was just get caught by it. Even if it is a bug and there shouldn't be one with capital D, it works.

Answer (score 7):

There's no built-in way to do this, but it wouldn't be hard to have any number of tests depend on some other test passing. You must ensure that `ATest` is executed before `BTest`.

```
class ATest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public static $passed = false;

    function testThatMustPass() {
        // ... the actual test ...
        // ok, test passed
        self::$passed = true;
    }
}

class BTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function testThatDependsOnA() {
        if (!ATest::$passed) {
            self::markTestSkipped('A failed');
        }
    }
}
```

Having tests depend on an entire test case is also possible.

```
class ATest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public static $passed = true;

    protected function onNotSuccessfulTest(Exception $e)
        self::$passed = false;
        parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($e);
    }
}
```

You could improve these by tracking the names of the tests that failed so you could depend on a subset of tests for each case.

Comment: Very helpful, though you have to somehow make sure test A runs before test B, so if not specifying order in an xml file, I suppose you just need to make sure they are named alphabetically.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like your tests are integrative, instead, and fail if distinct subsets are broken. I would encourage you to look up Mocks and Stubs. Only those are the proper answers to your question. Don't fall for hackish workarounds that will only hurt you in the long run.

http://phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: I have no idea why this answer from 2012 was deleted. It was the highest voted @ 11 points

Comment: Who said that integration tests is a bad thing? And you can't know what kind of tests the author had and what they were trying to achieve, so you should not assume that what you suggest is "the only proper answer".