# Writing test suites

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I know that everybody share the fact that unit testing should be unitary. But if you read the book, you notice that there is room to build test suites.

> Chapter 7. Organizing Tests
>   One of the goals of PHPUnit (see Chapter 2) is that tests should be composable: we want to be able to run any number or combination of tests together, for instance all tests for the whole > project, or the tests for all classes of a component that is part of the project, or just the tests for a single class.

Example 7.2: Composing a Test Suite Using XML Configuration

```
<phpunit>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Object_Freezer">
      <file>Tests/Freezer/HashGenerator/NonRecursiveSHA1Test.php</file>
      <file>Tests/Freezer/IdGenerator/UUIDTest.php</file>
      <file>Tests/Freezer/UtilTest.php</file>
      <file>Tests/FreezerTest.php</file>
      <file>Tests/Freezer/StorageTest.php</file>
      <file>Tests/Freezer/Storage/CouchDB/WithLazyLoadTest.php</file>
      <file>Tests/Freezer/Storage/CouchDB/WithoutLazyLoadTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

If you add the capability for tests dependencies:

> Test Dependencies
>
> Unit Tests are primarily written as a good practice to help developers identify and fix bugs, to re-factor code and to serve as documentation for a unit of software under test. To achieve these benefits, unit tests ideally should cover all the possible paths in a program. One unit test usually covers one specific path in one function or method. However a test method is not necessary an encapsulated, independent entity. Often there are implicit dependencies between test methods, hidden in the implementation scenario of a test.

You can use dependencies within a class or between classes with @depends ClassName::Function and use the data provided by the ClassName::Function.

For exemple if class A provides data also used in class B and C, you get:

```
A {
    function a()
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
B {
    /**
    * @depends A::a
    */
    function b($data)
    {
        return $data2;
    }
}
C {
    /**
    * @depends B::b
    */
    function c($data2)
    {
    }
}
```

Why is it so bad? is it better in your sense to duplicate code in A::a to the class B::b and then to duplicate code from class A::a and B::b to class C::c ?

I would like to learn best practice in your sense.. I always used tests suites before and unit testing is perfect to test independent functions but when you need to test whole services which relies on dpeendencies, it is a little more complex.. Should I discard completely PHPUnit for whose tests, what do you advice as replacement?

Comment: What fact does everybody share? What is unitary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835607/dependent-tests-between-two-testcase-classes-in-phpunit For exemple

Comment: The point of unit testing is in the word 'unit' which means you want to test *independent* units and not whole services. If every single small unit works, your code works. Unit tests are not meant to test if your whole architecture makes sense.

Comment: IMO Unitary means independent and function focused

Comment: Ok, then why does PHPUnit provides whose functionality and somewhat promote them in their documentation?

Comment: As the answer in the other question says. You still don't seem to really grasp the purpose of **unit** tests. Don't replace phpunit with anything. Write tests to cover all the paths in your app independently. That is the purpose of unit tests. They should not fail, if some other part of your app fails. Only if the small tested unit fails.

Comment: I totaly agree on the principle bu you will also agree that sometime a function is based on services that cannot be mocked, for example if you want to test that a DAO retrieve the rights value from database, you then have to populate the database in order to make your test, same thing if you are trying to work with a datafile

Comment: You should not have to populate your database, just provide a data mock. You don't want to test the database, you want to test if the right values are fetched.

Comment: In case you really, really can't mock a service, use @depends, that's what it's there for.

Comment: The thing is I used to do a lot of unit testing when I worked for electronic industry, it was easy to mock an electronic device.. The thing is that I do not understand yet how to mock a security layer or a database.. I tried to mock them in my code, but would always end up with some dependency problem. Do I need to build specific mocked services to unit test a function and build as many mock services as functions to test? this can be huge work..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20844/discussion-between-markus-tharkun-and-mylen)

Answer (score 0):

I will write the transcript of the discussion with markus-tharkun:

PHPUnit is aimed at unit testing, that means :

> The point of unit testing is in the word 'unit' which means you want to test independent units and not whole services. If every single small unit works, your code works. Unit tests are not meant to test if your whole architecture makes sense.

As I asked him, if you are testing a function that has dependencies, you can inject a Mock object to that function. You should mock all external dependencies for that function, including, security layer, user object, database access, everything. If you really cannot Mock a dependency, then you use @depends, but that should be avoided.

Markus adviced me to use the Mockery framework: https://github.com/padraic/mockery